# What is the data limit that Google Data Studio can handle?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

Does anyone have an experience with large data sets in Data Studio?

I want to use a data that is close to 40 million rows and a dozen columns. I was trying to check it by myself but after connection to BigQuery query a `Configuration error` occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dataset stored in BigQuery, Data Studio should have no problem handing it - through BigQuery. Size shouldn't really be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that when Data Studio accesses a BigQuery table, it is limited to 20,000,000 rows.

Specifically, LIMIT 20000000 is applied to the actual query in BQ and there is no way to configure / change that (to the best of my knowledge).